# How do I hit a url and read data using CFHTTP

Tags: iphone

How do I hit a url and read data using CFHTTP?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question as an actual question, we can't read your mind?

Comment: Please don't post duplicates (deleted) - clarify this question.

Answer (score 0):

Without more to your answer not much to answer but just in case...

```
<cfset url = some value>
<cfhttp url="#url#">
<cfdump var="#cfhttp#">
```

You can analyze the dump to see how to access what you'll need form the response.

Comment: I am fairly certain he is talking about the CoreFoundation http api (CFHTTP) on iPhone, not cold fusion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Louis. Might there be a way to tag this as CoreFoundation and not ColdFusion / CFML?